# Excel, combining two sheets on a third sheet by matching names

Tags: excel, matching

I am working on creating a database of information based on 2 spreadsheet. What is in common about them is that they have the names of people. However, not everyone has data/information for all the other columns. Is there a way to write a formula or code it so that I can get information to populate in a third sheet to say if the names are the same put this information here? I've put an example below. sheet 1 is name and location, sheet two is name is number, and sheet three is what I would like it to look like as an end product.
[picture of what im going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf4eR.png)

Comment: Look into `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX/MATCH`. I think those will do what you want

Comment: Thank you! INDEX/MATCH worked really well

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above mentions, you can use VLOOKUP (or INDEX/MATCH) for this.  I would also wrap the entire statment in an IF and ISERROR so if there isn't a match it will return a empty string.

Something like this:

```
IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(G4,$D$2:$E$3,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(G4,$D$2:$E$3,2,FALSE))
```

Assume col A:B is your location table, D:E is your Number table, and G:I is the combined table where you put your VLOOKUPs

[See this image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foavu.png)

Comment: Thank you so much I was able to use get the necessary table i wanted with this!

Comment: is the formula different for index match? I originally used index match, so i just copied that and replaced the VLOOKUP(.....E)) parts and it says I put in too many arguments

Comment: yes, INDEX/MATCH would be slightly different but would get you the same result.  Generally, INDEX/MATCH is just a bit more flexible than VLOOKUP, but I often prefer VLOOKUP just because the syntax is a bit more straightforward and it's just easier to be lazy.  There are a lot of good references on Index match, try:  https://exceljet.net/index-and-match